# How to improve invert + grayscale operator in Java?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, grayscale, boofcv

I want to invert and gray scale an image. Here is my original image:
[image]

Here is the final result I want to achieve (produced with Paint.NET):
[image]

However using some (basic?) Java code found on Internet, I only get the picture below:
[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
private static final byte[] invertTable;

static {
    invertTable = new byte[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        invertTable[i] = (byte) (255 - i);
    }
}

private static BufferedImage grayScale(BufferedImage source) {
    ColorConvertOp grayScale = new ColorConvertOp(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY), null);

    return grayScale.filter(source,null);
}

private static BufferedImage invertImage(final BufferedImage src) {
    final int w = src.getWidth();

    final int h = src.getHeight();

    final BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    final BufferedImageOp invertOp = new LookupOp(new ByteLookupTable(0, invertTable), null);

    return invertOp.filter(src, dst);
}

// ...
BufferedImage sourceImage = ...
BufferedImage convertedImage = grayScale(invertImage(sourceImage));
```

How can I improve the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Imgproc` and `Core`, I did

```
Mat src = new Mat();
Mat gray = new Mat();
src = Highgui.imread("...");
Imgproc.cvtColor(src, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Core.bitwise_not(gray, gray);
Highgui.imwrite("...", gray);
```

and got something closer, though not identical:

[image: OpenCV default grayscale mapping + bitwise invert]

Comment: Which Maven dependency should I use to get `Imgproc` and `Core`?

Comment: I am only getting started with Java, and haven't gotten to using Maven yet. I followed the directions in http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html#create-a-simple-java-project-in-eclipse, and added `import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;`  Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

In the title it says OpenCV but there's a tag for BoofCV.  So here's how to do it in BoofCV:

```
BufferedImage orig = UtilImageIO.loadImage("filename");
ImageUInt8 gray = ConvertBufferedImage.convertFrom(orig, (ImageUInt8) null);
ImageUInt8 inverted = new ImageUInt8(gray.width,gray.height);
GrayImageOps.invert(gray,255,inverted);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you complete your answer with the final picture please?

Comment: The difference is probably caused by average being used instead of weighted average when converting to grey.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not familiar with ColorConvertOp, I would suspect that it is converting the color image to greyscale in a different way then Paint.NET is.  There is no correct way.

Take a look at the yellow.  Should yellow be a dark or light grey?  It looks like Paint.NET thinks it is light and the ColorConvertOp thinks it is dark.

Try doing the conversion yourself by just averaging the red/green/blue.

```
(red+green+blue)/3
```

Comment: Be warned: the average of color components is one way to get a grayscale image, but it doesn't match the sensitivity of human eyes to different colors. Doing a weighted average will give results that probably "look better". A quick overview can be found [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/)

Comment: As Aurelius says there are many ways to do it, each attempting to make the image, better, and more accurate.  In most applications it doesn't really matter which approach is taken.